# How can I get a property value from the header of a Logic Apps response?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have created a small Logic App that queries CDS. The response is chunked and I need the value of the property "x-ms-request-id" from "headers".

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
        "Vary": "Accept-Encoding",
        "x-ms-request-id": "some-guid",
        "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
        "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
        "X-Frame-Options": "DENY",
        "Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "true",
        "Cache-Control": "no-store, no-cache",
        "Date": "Tue, 15 Sep 2020 07:48:56 GMT",
        "Set-Cookie": "ARRAffinity=something;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=commondataservice-cus.azconn-cus.p.azurewebsites.net",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8; odata.metadata=minimal",
        "Expires": "-1",
        "Content-Length": "3498648"
    },
    "body": {
        "@odata.context": "some url",
        "value": [....],
        "@odata.nextLink": "another url"
    }
}
```

I have tried using `@triggerOutputs()?['headers']?['x-ms-request-id']` without any success.

[image: Set variable]

When the Logic App runs the variable token gets assigned the `null` value.
[image]

Comment: Could you please have a try with this expression `triggerBody()?['headers']?['x-ms-request-id']` ?

Comment: @HuryShen I have tried that as well. Same 'null' result.

Comment: May I know where the json data you provided in question come from ? Could you please share more details of your logic app ?

Comment: I'm trying to get all the records for a particular entity from Common Data Service. The response is chunked and I'm only getting the first 512 records. From my research I need to use the `x-ms-request-id` value as an authentication token to get the next chunk.

Comment: It seems the json data come from the schedule trigger ?

Comment: The json comes from the "List records" action

Comment: So why do you get the value of "x-ms-request-id" from trigger but not from the "List records" action ?

Comment: Why not use "Parse JSON" to parse the result of "List records" and then get the "x-ms-request-id" value ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221500/discussion-between-hury-shen-and-gogutz).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get value of "**x-ms-request-id**" in headers by the expression below:

```
outputs('List_records')?['headers']?['x-ms-request-id']
```